# Why are all my menus open/garbled?

Tags: menu, drupal-8, pantheon

My menus look like this:
[image]

For background: This is Drupal 8.  The menus were fine, but I'm porting the site to Pantheon.  My Browser dev tools say that all my files (inc. CSS/JS) are loading properly.  There are no JS console errors.  My non-Pantheon site doesn't have this behavior, though I've had to make changes to the site to make it work in Pantheon (mainly in Composer) but I can't think of what else could cause this.

*Edit:* I compared the actual CSS files - `builder.css` is different on my non-Pantheon site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of missing the `bower_components` folder, which should be in your CiviCRM module's root folder.